# PySpark reduceByKey on multiple values

Tags: pyspark

If I have a K,V pair that is like:

```
(K, (v1, v2))
(K, (v3, v4))
```

How can I sum up the values such that I get
`(k, (v1 + v3, v2 + v4))` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

reduceByKey supports functions. Lets say A is the array of the Key-Value pairs.

```
output = A.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1])
```

Comment: Perhaps should have been `output = A.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]))`