# Pyspark reduceByKey on nested tuples

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, reduce

My question is similar to [PySpark reduceByKey on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831530/pyspark-reducebykey-on-multiple-values) but with a somehow critical difference. I am new to PySpark, so I am for sure missing something obvious.

I have an RDD with the following structure:

```
(K0, ((k01,v01), (k02,v02), ...))
....
(Kn, ((kn1,vn1), (kn2,vn2), ...))
```

What I want as an output is something like

```
(K0, v01+v02+...)
...
(Kn, vn1+vn2+...)
```

This seems like the perfect case to use `reduceByKey` and at first I thought of something like

```
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x[1]+y[1])
```

Which gives me exactly the RDD I began with. I suppose there is something wrong with my indexing, as there are nested tuples, but I have tried every possible index combination I could think of and it keeps on giving me back the initial RDD.

Is there maybe a reason why it shouldn't work with nested tuples or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `reduceByKey` here at all. It takes an associative and commutative function with signature. `(T, T) => T`. It should be obvious that it is not applicable when you have `List[Tuple[U, T]]` as an input and you expect `T` as an output.

Since it is not exactly clear if keys or unique or not lets consider general example when we have to aggregate both locally and globally. Lets assume that `v01`, `v02`, ... `vm` are simple numerics:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def agg_(xs):
    # For numeric values sum would be more idiomatic
    # but lets make it more generic
    return reduce(add, (x[1] for x in xs), zero_value)

zero_value = 0
merge_op = add
def seq_op(acc, xs):
    return acc + agg_(xs)

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ("K0", (("k01", 3), ("k02", 2))),
    ("K0", (("k03", 5), ("k04", 6))),
    ("K1", (("k11", 0), ("k12", -1)))])

rdd.aggregateByKey(0, seq_op, merge_op).take(2)
## [('K0', 16), ('K1', -1)]
```

If keys are already unique simple `mapValues` will suffice:

```
from itertools import chain

unique_keys = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: tuple(chain(*x)))
unique_keys.mapValues(agg_).take(2)
## [('K0', 16), ('K1', -1)]
```

Comment: That is now clear to me. Yes, keys are unique, so the mapValues approach is just what I need. Thank you very much.