# PySpark reduceByKey with multiple values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So while I have the identical title as this question: [PySpark reduceByKey on multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831530/pyspark-reducebykey-on-multiple-values)

I cannot get the answer to work for what I want to do.

```
A = sc.parallelize([("a", (1,0)), ("b", (4,2)),("a", (11,2)), ("b", (4,10))])
A.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]).collect()
```

Gives me the error:

```
name 'x' is not defined
```

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  Some parenthesis:

```
A.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0] ,x[1]+y[1])).collect()
```